# Java Migration: Apache Camel moved to 3.0 but Maven not able to download jars

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

I changed camel version to 3.0.0 from 2X during Java Migration.

```
<version.apache.camel>3.0.0</version.apache.camel>
```

When i build everything then i get following in eclipse

[image]

[image]

but all camel class turns not readable.

I explode jar in maven directory using decompiler and i get following :

[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue with 3.0.0? Is maven repository creating issue?

Comment: And what does that mean: `..Maven not able to download jars`  errors? Log file? Have you tried to build on plain command line? Which Maven version etc..

Comment: it worked at sudden, no co mates were able to download. 
and now everyone can, no server issue nothing; and now all are stunned !!!!